# Parâmetro SQL no PDO PHP não funciona

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite

O seguinte código retorna 11 registros do banco:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:db_coleta.sqlite3');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROTA_VIEW WHERE usuario_id = 1 AND  0 = 0');
$sth->execute();
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($red);
```

Porém o seguinte código, utilizando parametro, não retorna nenhum registro(o que é errado):

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:db_coleta.sqlite3');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROTA_VIEW WHERE usuario_id = ? AND  0 = 0');
$sth->execute(array(1));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($red);
```

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo errado, pois estou seguindo exemplos da documentação do php, esta tudo igual, só que para minha problematica. Não consigo entender porque isto não funciona, visto que é a mesma coisa que o seguinte exemplo(retirado de http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php):

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(175, 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os parâmetros você não passa no método `execute()`. Você joga no método `bindValue()`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? AND name=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[Referência](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: Ok, funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: Tenha sempre uma referência, documentação com você, pra não se perder nas coisas básicas.
E lembre-se, o bindValue() não garante a segurança dos dados, ele serve pra poder reaproveitar a query.

Comment: Sim, sempre verifico, porém escapou a seguinte frase do manual: "All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR."(http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php).
Enfim, eu tinha outras querys executando antes, porém apenas com parametros do tipo string, então da maneira que tinha  feito dava certo. 
Enfim, alterei para usar o bindParam, como sugerido.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente fazer um `bindParam` ao invés de passar o `array` de parâmetros no `execute`:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:db_coleta.sqlite3');

$usuario_id = 150;

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROTA_VIEW WHERE usuario_id = :usuario_id AND 0 = 0');
$sth->bindParam(':usuario_id', $usuario_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

$red = $sth->fetchAll();

var_dump($red);
```

---

Uma atenção ao que o [@MatheusPicioli](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/68085/matheus-picioli) referiu, fazer `bindValue` e `bindParam` é diferente! O `bindValue` é avaliado no momento em que é atribuído ao parâmetro, enquanto que o `bindParam` é no momento em que o `execute` é evocado.

### Com `bindValue`:

```
$usuario_id = 150;

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROTA_VIEW WHERE usuario_id = :usuario_id AND 0 = 0');
$sth->bindValue(':usuario_id', $usuario_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$usuario_id = 200;

$sth->execute();     // executado com 'WHERE usuario_id = 150'
```

### Com `bindParam`:

```
$usuario_id = 150;

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROTA_VIEW WHERE usuario_id = :usuario_id AND 0 = 0');
$sth->bindParam(':usuario_id', $usuario_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$usuario_id = 200;

$sth->execute();     // executado com 'WHERE usuario_id = 200'
```

Comment: Muito bom, certamente vai ajudar as demais pessoas que estiverem meio perdidas igual eu. Optei pelo uso do bindParam, que acabou se enquadrando melhor na minha problemática.

Comment: Ainda bem que ajudou alguém :)! Marque a resposta como útil!